# Sublime Text's tab completion in Emacs

Tags: emacs, sublimetext2

Is there a widely used plugin in Emacs which allows me to do the same tab completion and "Going to anything" in Sublime Text?

`ThisFunctionHasAVeryLongName()` can be done by typing `tfaln`[tab] for example.
`/here/is/another/long/path/file` can be done by typing `hereanlfile`[tab]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something in the Emacs Wiki called "flexible expand".  I have not tried it myself.  See also other tips on the page: http://emacswiki.org/emacs/HippieExpand#toc8